# How to query multiple lists using Content Query WebPart (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part, query

On root site I have Country Sub site it contains multiple Sub sites with country name like (ABC, DEF)
each sub site contains calendar list.

- root site

  - Country

    ```
    - ABC 
    - DEF
    - HIJ
    - XYZ
    ```

on **root site** I have Content Query web part,
Now I am trying to displays data from multiple Calendar lists .

So is that possible to query multiple list using Content query webpart?
If not please suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to query multiple subsite with a content query web part.

You only need to find the correct match (display template) or be able to edit in XML the one that is closer.